# FlatList scrollToEnd not working in Android with Redux

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist

`ScrollToEnd()` (on a `FlatList`) appears to have no effect in Android (or in the iOS simulator). The refs appear to be correct, and my own `scrollEnd` function is being called (I was desperate) but nothing changes on the screen. The effects of all the scroll functions appear to be really inconsistent - I can get `scrollToOffset` to work on iOS but not Android. I read that this may be because Android doesn't know the height of the items in the flatlist, but it still doesn't work with `getItemLayout` implemented.

There's no feedback/errors I can see which would explain why this wouldn't work. Note that I am developing with Redux, using Android 7.0 to test and am trying this in Debugging mode (using `react-native run-android`). The `FlatList` is inside a normal `View` (not a `ScrollView`).

The logic in the code is correct as far as I can tell, but calling `scrollToEnd` on the `FlatList` has no visible effect.
My `render()` function:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.inner}>
    <FlatList
      ref={(ref) => { this.listRef = ref; }}
      data = {this.getConversation().messages || []}
      renderItem = {this.renderRow}
      keyExtractor = {(item) => item.hash + ''}
      numColumns={1}
      initialNumToRender={1000}
      onContentSizeChange={() => {
        this.scrollToEnd();
      }}
      getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
        {length: 50, offset: 50 * index, index}
      )}
      onContentSizeChange={this.scrollToEnd()}
      onLayout={ this.scrollToEnd()}
      onScroll={ this.scrollToEnd()}
   />
  </View>
</View>
```

`this.scrollToEnd()`:

```
scrollToEnd = () => {
    console.log("scrolling func"); // This is printed
    const wait = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
    wait.then( () => {
        console.log("scrolling"); // This is also printed
        this.listRef.scrollToEnd(); // Throws no errors, has no effect?
    });
};
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct to me, but which version of React are you using? Starting from v16.3 the recommended way to use refs is through React.createRef(), so your code would be change to:

```js
// constructor
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.flatlistRef = React.createRef();
}

// inside render
<FlatList
  ref={this.flatlistRef}
  ...
/>

// scrollToEnd
scrollToEnd = () => {
  this.flatlistRef.current.scrollToEnd(); // ref.current refers to component
};
```

Note that this might not solve your problem, since the older usage of ref should still be valid